# how to set up an inline svg with webpack

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs, webpack, loader

I am wondering how to set up an inline svg with webpack?

I am following the [react-webpack-cookbook](https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Loading-SVG).

I have my **webpack.config** set up correctly with the **file loader**.

However the example shows using a background image like this:

```
.icon {
   background-image: url(./logo.svg);
}
```

which works fine, but I want to have an inline svg image how do I do this to include my **logo.svg** inline in my react component?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <img src={'./logo.svg'} />
        </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Header
```

Answer (score 39):

Here is a simple non-react solution.

1. Install [Svg inline loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader)
2. In webpack.config.js add  `{ test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-inline-loader' }`
3. In your js file import svg image and add it to a DOM element like so

```
  import Svg from './svg.svg';

  function component() {
    const element = document.createElement('div');

    element.innerHTML = Svg;

    return element;
  }

  document.body.appendChild(component());
```

Comment: kudos for not relying on react and presenting vanilla ECMAScript

Answer (score 36):

Actually Michelle's answer pointed me in the right direction, and that works nicely for loading an svg file with webpack and using it as your `<img>` src

However to actually get the inline svg, I needed to do the following:

Instead of file-loader use [svg-inline-loader](https://github.com/sairion/svg-inline-loader) as your svg loader:

`{ test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-inline-loader' }`

Then to load the svg inline in a component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import logo from "./logo.svg";

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div className='header'>
          <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: logo}} />
        </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Header
```

It looks like there is an inline svg wrapper for react [svg-inline-react](https://github.com/sairion/svg-inline-react) which would be another option instead of the `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mySvg}} />`

Comment: just a note, this does not work at all with server rendering... so is not as useful as I once thought. I have gone back to using an svg as a background image. It does also seem to bloat the JavaScript bundle as well like inline svg's do, of course this would depend on how optimized the svgs are.

Comment: There is a good case study posted by Twitter which shows up why you should *not* use 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' for displaying SVGs: https://medium.com/@paularmstrong/twitter-lite-and-high-performance-react-progressive-web-apps-at-scale-d28a00e780a3#3732

Answer (score 33):

I hope my late answer will still be useful for someone, because I don't like any of abovementioned options.

The [react-svg-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader) webpack loader allows you to import SVG icons like JSX components:

```
import Logo from './logo.svg';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Logo fill="red" className="logo" width={50} height={50} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and minimum config looks like this:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "babel-loader"
    },
    {
      loader: "react-svg-loader",
      options: {
        jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The best part is that it just outputs the svg file contents, without any extra wrappers and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in your code.

Comment: This works perfect with latest React 16.10 and Webpack 4.41. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Old question, but I didn't see this solution anywhere so I decided to post it, hoping it will help someone.

If you want to be able to style those SVG icons, you might want to load them with the raw loader:

webpack.config.js:

```
 { 
      test: /\.svg$/, 
      loader: 'raw-loader' 
 }
```

The import in my view:

```
import closeIcon from 'svg/ic_close_black_24px.svg';
```

The template (Mustache uses 3 brackets to insert the SVG data (URL)unencoded):

```
<button id="closeModal">
  {{{closeIcon}}}
</button>
```

this way the SVG data will be inserted instead of the brackets and look like this:

```
<button id="closeModal">
  <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
  </svg>
</button>
```

I'm using Backbone  with Mustache template engine with Webpack 2.5.1

Comment: Going to work with a string-template based library like backbone + mustache or vue, but not with react because it uses JSX instead of raw strings. Probably does work with "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" though...

Answer (score 12):

If I'm not mistaken, since you're using the file loader, you can utilize it in much the same way as any other require. Webpack will turn `require("./logo.svg")` into a path to a file, which it will emit when it bundles.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import mySvg from './logo.svg'

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <img src={mySvg} />
        </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Header
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( could you post your webpack.config.js? Maybe I can spot my mistake there.

Comment: Worked for me only after I restarted `npm start`

Comment: and this adds the svg inline?

or does it wrap the svg within an image tag?

Answer (score 6):

Similar to another answer using React, there is also a handy Vue plugin as well.

[vue-svg-loader](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader) just throw it in your configuration and start using. The nice thing is it will also run your svg through SVGO to optimize it.

**Configuration**

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
  loader: 'vue-svg-loader', // `vue-svg` for webpack 1.x
  options: {
    // optional [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) options
    svgo: {
      plugins: [
        {removeDoctype: true},
        {removeComments: true}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<template>
  <nav id="menu">
    <a href="...">
      <SomeIcon class="icon" />
      Some page
    </a>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import SomeIcon from './assets/some-icon.svg';

export default {
  name: 'menu',
  components: {
    SomeIcon,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular Solution (2019): Use [svg-sprite-loader](https://github.com/kisenka/svg-sprite-loader) to combine SVGs into a single sprite that's lazy-loaded with your Webpack bundles.

Webpack

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    'svg-sprite-loader',
    'svgo-loader' // Optimize SVGs (optional)
  ]
}
```

HTML

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#arrow"/>
</svg>
```

Angular Component

```
export * from 'assets/images/icons/arrow.svg';
```

I use export (instead of import) to prevent the AOT compiler from removing the import during tree-shaking, while allowing for minimal code in the component, but you can [use import](https://github.com/kisenka/svg-sprite-loader#runtime-configuration) if you prefer.

To use export in this way, you must configure the compiler to expect side effects from SVG files in package.json (i.e. you can not use "sideEffects": false). See the [Webpack Tree Shaking Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking)

```
"sideEffects": [
    "*.svg",
],
```

Answer (score 1):

[@svgr/webpack](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/tree/master/packages/webpack) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack)) is the inline svg loader that [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev) uses.

Add the rule to your webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
}
```

Then you can import svgs as React components:

```
import Star from './star.svg'

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Star />
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Folks who use `svg-inline-loader` and who stuck with "Cannot find module" error try to install `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg` and add it to the babel plugins:

```
"plugins": [
    ...
    ["inline-react-svg", {}]
],
...
```