# ReactJS not showing SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, meteor

I have tried to make a loading spinner for my website, but I cant seem to get it to work. I get the error in the console, that the site was unable to load the SVG file. Would be great if someone could locate the problem and help me by looking at the screenshots below:

[Picture of my Spinner component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lELAF.png)

[Picture of my App component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpADk.png)

Comment: this is likely to do with an svg / inline-svg loader in your webpack config and not react itself.

Comment: you might found this link helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257800/how-to-set-up-an-inline-svg-with-webpack