# How to import svg files and use them for src in image

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to solve.

I have a svg file that I need to include in my project. Since I've build my own boilerplate I want to have the same functionality as *CRA* in that I can use the svg as the image src.

i.e.

```
<img src={svgfile} alt="some file" />
```

What would I need to do to have that functionality?
I tried to use file loader to get it to work but it throws an error.

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {}
      }
    ]
  },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SA

**webpack file**

```
{
  entry: "./src/browser/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: "babel-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: "true"
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please give the sample of your  `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: @JunedLanja added

Comment: `webpack.config.js` looks good. What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you running `webpack` command to create `bundle.js`

Comment: this is the command I'm using to create the `bundle.js` file. `webpack -w & nodemon server.js`

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I didnt close the dev server after i made the refresh. Im sorry to have wasted you time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181126/discussion-between-juned-lanja-and-strahinja-ajvaz).

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: You can try `svg-inline-loader` https://webpack.js.org/loaders/svg-inline-loader/. Or you can use `babel-loader` with an Babel plugin, https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set up an inline svg with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257800/how-to-set-up-an-inline-svg-with-webpack)

Answer (score 3):

Like

```
 import svgfile from “./path/fileName.svg”;

 <img src={svgfile} alt="some file" />
```

Or

```
<img src={require(“./path/fileName.svg”} alt="some file" />
```

Please excuse me for double quotes I am answering in mobile

Comment: Will only work if @Strahinja Ajvaz has properly configured webpack

Comment: @JunedLanja It renders all the other loaders properly, transpiles jsx to js and es6 to es5. this is the only one thats giving me trouble.

Comment: @StrahinjaAjvaz  Kindly do upvote and accept the answer on your choice whichever answer resolved your query. So that it will help future readers

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
test: /\.(?:png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
use: [
  {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'assets/[hash].[ext]',
    }
  },
]
```

Where `assets` is directory where imported file will be stored after build.