# Inline an SVG file in Vue with v-bind feature on source

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuejs2, quasar-framework

Final Goal : Include SVG icons from files with the possibility to use CSS on it (mainly on the `fill` parameter). This seems to mean having a way to inline the SVG file in the Vue template.

I have found plenty of solutions involving webpack loaders (`vue-svg-inline-loader`, `vue-svg-loader`, and 2 or 3 others), but I also want to be able to choose dynamically which file I load by using a v-bind directive on the source parameter. Something like :

```
<img :src="`path/to/${file}.svg`" />
```

or

```
<custom-component :src="`path/to/${file}.svg`" />
```

And none of the webpack loaders seems to allow that. I found no vue plug-in with this feature.

My porject is a `quasar-framework` project, if this can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that:

```
<template v-html="svgFile"></template>
...
computed:{
  svgFile(){
    require(`path/to/${this.file}.svg`)
  }
}
```

But you also need config your webpack to out put your svg as raw html. Using some plugin like `svg-inline-loader` or whatever you want. [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257800/how-to-set-up-an-inline-svg-with-webpack)

```
{ test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-inline-loader' }
```

Comment: This does not work, first, the `file` parameter cannot be used here since computed properties do not accept parameters, but even when trying with a static (valid) path for now, nothing is displayed (and no error thrown, sadly).

Comment: @Tom Try inspecting to your template and see if the inline svg exists but you can not see it?

Comment: I used another (similar) workaround: `<div v-html="item.icon"></div>` with a `v-for` loop on `item` in `items`. It's half satisfying since I still have to declare each icon path in my `items` but I already spent too many hours on this, and I don't think I can get any closer, see https://github.com/oliverfindl/vue-svg-inline-loader/issues/2